# Axon Framework tables names with Oracle + Spring jpa table autogeneration

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, axon

I am using Axon Framework 4.1 (without Axon Server) with Oracle 12.1 and Spring Boot Jpa 2.3.0

When the application starts I am using hibernate via this property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to generate all my tables including Axon's tables. As a result I got the names in this format `DOMAIN_EVENT_ENTRY`, `TOKEN_ENTRY` etc..
After that, when I send a command, I got the following error message: `An event for aggregate [2] at sequence [0] could not be persisted`.

I think this is because Axon searching for the table with the name: `DOMAINEVENTENTRY` and not finding it and I got the error message. When I renamed `DOMAIN_EVENT_ENTRY` table to `DOMAINEVENTENTRY` everything started working well.

If I guess well this is the problem. But on the other hand I used Axon with H2 and it worked with the name `DOMAIN_EVENT_ENTRY`, so I guess its an Oracle specific issue?

So my question is how can I configure the Axon tables name to generate the tables in the right name without hacking.

And think it would be good in this case a more detailed error message. Why my event can't be persisted.

My properties related with the question:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Thanks,
Mate

Comment: Hello polosoft, this seems to be due to the naming strategy and databases using case-insensitive table names. Can we check your `application.properties` or `application.yml`?

Comment: updated the question with properties, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update... I found more things related to this: "The default Naming Strategy of Hibernate creates arbitrary long names, which do not work with Oracle which has a (very annoying) limit of 30 characters for names.". So probably it is using a different Naming Strategy by default. Can you try to change it and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks I answered my own question, but It would be a nice feature in the furute to support this, and change the error message. Thanks, Máté

Comment: Glad to help, thanks for the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Here is the answer:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

This create the tables in this style: DOMAINEVENTENTRY etc..